# Content border not showing in any browser!

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been working on a project for a few days now and have just recently noticed that the border of 2 of my content areas are not showing in Mozilla or IE.

http://www.gamefriction.com/Coded/ is where the page is located. If you look at the main content area where the "news" is you will see that there is a 1px solid border that is a slightly darker grey than the 4px border surrounding each content box.

On the right column content the 1px solid #dfdfdf; border does not show.

I can't seem to find any reason why this is not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: I do see it in FF 3.6 and Google Chrome 5.0.3.
Hint: try changing the color to red, so it will be easy to spot if it's there or not.

Comment: What is the "right column content" you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does show up, the 1px border on the left column (news/main area) is #DFDFDF, but the 3px border surrounding the page is #EAEAEA. Meanwhile, on the right column, both borders are #DFDFDF. So your #blue_modal_wrap should have: "border: 3px solid #EAEAEA;"

Answer (score 1):

The border is showing in Chrome. After inspecting it, I realized that you have the border set to `#DFDFDF` for both borders, which is why you don't see it as existing.

Comment: @RussellUresti Oh ok, I see. I somehow copied and pasted the wrong hash color code when I was making the right column. Thanks for pointing that out. I was looking more for errors in the code than a dumb mistake like that which is why i overlooked it so many times lol!